# Creating a virtualenv with already created django app

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am trying to deploy my django app in to production on a centos server.  I have an app running on my computer(not server) with a code repository that doesn't utilize a virtual environment, and i wish i had set that up to begin with. I would like the production stage of the django app be run with a virtual environment, and was wondering what was the best way to go about this.

I am very cloudy on how this would work out. Would i need to set up the django app on my computer with a virtual environment, and then move the code repository to the server and go about it that way?

My understanding is the purpose of the virtual environment is to keep tabs and easily install any dependecies and software updates need to run the django app.

So the question is: Should i not worry about setting up a virtual environment on my computer, but start one on my server and start from there?  Or would i run into problems when i try to `git clone` my project to the server because there isnt a virtualenv setup from the repository.

And if i should have it setup up on my local django app on my computer, how to i go about setting it up on an existing webapp?

Comment: How your project runs on your own computer or the fact its an existing app is irrelevant, all you need is the requirements file that details what dependencies your project needs

Comment: In order to be sure that you install the correct packages on your server, you should have a file in your repository that lists all the dependencies. If you use standard `pip` , then a requirements.txt file that you can install with `pip install -r requirements.txt` would replicate the same environment on multiple machines. So you should first create the virtualenv on your local machine and check if your app is running correctly after the `pip install...`. Then you can use the same requirements file on your server to update your virtualenv. An alternative is to use `pipenv`, more robust.

Answer (score 1):

The app doesn't care whether it's running in a virtualenv or not. You can simply create a new virtualenv on the server and redeploy the app inside it, reinstall the dependencies, then point your web server at the new app.